# The value [value] is not assigned in input

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a little problem using [value] in my inputs.

This is my component .html

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" style="padding-left: 15px;">
        <input matInput  [value]='value_2_' [(ngModel)]="form.name_1"   placeholder="name_1"  
         name="name_pro_1" required>
</mat-form-field>
 </div>
```

Everything looks good, but when I run the program, the value is shown in the corresponding input, however, being a value required by the input, it is still in red, it is solved until I add a letter to the value or remove something from the input.
[image: Image code running]

I managed to solve the error by deleting

> name = "name_pro_1"

[image: Image code running without name="name_pro_1"]

but since I use NgModel I cannot remove the name because I get other errors. Like:

> core.js:4352 ERROR Error: If ngModel is used within a form tag, either the name attribute must be set or the form
> control must be defined as 'standalone' in ngModelOptions.

```
  Example 1: <input [(ngModel)]="person.firstName" name="first">
  Example 2: <input [(ngModel)]="person.firstName" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is `[(ngModel)]="form.name_1"`. Try to replace that with

`[(ngModel)]="testValue"` and define a variable in the class with the same name and it will work.

Comment: I changed my code, but it doesn't works, i defined my variable in my component.ts like: public testValue = this.form.name_1 and in my NgModel i replaced for [(ngModel)]="testValue" but result are the same. 
Am I doing something wrong in the syntax of my formTest variable?

Comment: You may share a sample of your code so we can see where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

I can't replicate the problem, but using [(ngModel)] doesn't make using [value] unnecessary? You can set the form.name_1 to the value you want on the component.ts file.

Comment: thank you for your answer, i do this changes in my component.ts but the results are the same. in my components.ts i declared: testValue = this.form.name_1 and in my NgModel i replaced for [(ngModel)]="testValue". Am i doing something wrong in the syntax of my testValue variable?

Comment: @EstuardoValenzuela Can you try adding the #inputName="ngModel" value to your input tag.
Here is a link with more information about using ngModel. [NgModel](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel)

Comment: well i adding #name_pro_1="ngModel" and delete the name = "name_pro_1" it seems to work but in the console I get the error: core.js: 4352 ERROR Error: If ngModel is used within a form tag, either the name attribute must be set or the form
      control must be defined as 'standalone' in ngModelOptions.

I add what it tells me and that's where it stops working, when I add the name = "name_pro_1" or when I add [ngModelOptions] = "{standalone: ​​true}"

Answer (score 0):

Finally i resolved the issue, that it's my solution:
First thing first, i delete the [(ngModel)] in the input of component.html, then i used (change) to call the function when user select a SKU

```
  <div class="form-group input-sku" >
                              <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                                  <mat-label>SKU</mat-label>
                                  <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." id="sku_select" aria-label="number"
                                        matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto"
                                        [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" (change)="changedata_1($event)" >
                                  <mat-autocomplete autoActiveFirstOption #auto="matAutocomplete">
                                  <mat-option *ngFor="let data of filter_products | async" [value]="data.sku">{{data.sku}}</mat-option>
                                </mat-autocomplete>
                              </mat-form-field>
                            </div>
```

Input who recived the value:

```
 <div class="form-group inputs-name">
                              <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                                <mat-label>Name</mat-label>
                                <input type="text" matInput  id="nombre_1"  required [value]="name_1" name="name_1" placeholder="Name" >
                              </mat-form-field>
                            </div>
```

And in my component.ts

```
changedata_1(e) {
this.nombre_1 = e.target.value;
this.DataToSave.nombre_1 = this.nombre_1;}

private _filter(value: string): Products_BD[] {
const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();
const data_ = this.DatasProducts.filter(DataProducts => DataProducts.sku.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue));
for(let element of data_){
  const sku1= elemento.sku;
  const name1 = element.name;
 
  this.name_1 = name1;
  this.DataToSave.sku_1 = sku1;
  this.DataToSave.name_1 = name1;

}

return this.DataProducts.filter(DataProducts => DataProducts.sku.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue));}
    this.filter_products = this.myControl.valueChanges.pipe(
  startWith(''),
  map(value => this._filter(value))
);
```

I hope this solution helps! :)